# OWASP Orizon implementation

Tags: owasp

I am working on developing a efficient tool for source code security testing.I have looked into OWASP's Orizon project. It looked interesting. But I am not able to get proper example implementations and documentation for the same. Can any one help me in doing it??

Answer (score 0):

The source code of last version of OWASP Orizon (currently 1.39) is available on [github](https://github.com/thesp0nge/owasp-orizon) but you will need to tweak the ant `build.xml` to build it. You can also download the binary version (1.19) on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/orizon/files/orizon-devel/v1.19/orizon_bin_1.19.tar.gz/download). You then just have to extract the `tar.gz` and run the `orizon.sh` that will give you a command prompt.

The available commands are the following:

```
* open directory_name: opens directory_name for scanning.
* model: creates an application model from the opened directory.
* stat: prints out some statistics coming from orizon engines
* crawl: performs a code crawling
* set option [value]: sets the option telling orizon how to behave
    valid option are:
        + mirage [trace|notrace]: trace and notrace to put the engine in 
        trace or in no trace mode.
        + quiet: says orizon to run quietly
        + store_output: says orizon not to use standard output to 
        print informations (valuable only for development team)
        + orl_root directory: specifies an alternative root for security 
        library overriding lib/orizon-library-1.19.jar
        + report_format [txt|html|xml|console]: specifies the output 
        format. Using console, output onto disk 
        will be disabled.
        + report_name filename: write report in filename, stored in the 
        directory you launch osh from.
* report: prints out the findings report
* version: prints the version number
* info: prints the version number and the available engines signature
```